# Jetpack Compose - Maintain the scroll state of Text with large text

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, vertical-scrolling

I have one `Text` composable inside a `Column`. The `Text` is displaying a very large string and therefore it scrolls. But when user moves to second screen and then comes back, the scroll state of `Text` is lost and it starts to display the string from the top.

I'm attaching the GIF of what's going on below:

https://freeimage.host/i/HdBWQJj

Following is my code:

```
ComposeListScrollingTheme {

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "first") {
            composable("first") {
                FirstScreen()
            }

            composable("second") {
                SecondScreen()
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            delay(3000)
            navController.navigate("second")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstScreen() {

    var str by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        str = "First Screen\n\n\n" + (1..1000).toList().joinToString()
    }

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = str,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            text = "Second Screen"
        )
    }
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated.